# Powershell Split based on new line

Tags: powershell

I have a text file which I import using `Get-Content`
It looks like this:

```
aago go sdf
bbbgo go sdf gojh
go

zzzz bbb
go

sdkfgo go sdfd
go
```

I want to `-split` it based on 'go' which is single liner "go", aka i want 3 array items only. So `-split 'go'` won't work.

How to specify delimiter for split where the only item in line in 'go', OR where after 'go' there is a new line?

So output I expect is this

```
$output[0]=
"aago go sdf
bbbgo go sdf gojh
"

$output[1]=
"zzzz bbb
"

$output[2]=
"sdkfgo go sdfd
"
```

Comment: So you're looking to split but also keep the `go` right?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, it doens't really matter, with or without go

Comment: all i want is the lines above that go

Comment: `-split '\r?\n\s*go\s*' -ne ''` might do the trick but better wait for someone actually good with regex to answer your question

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, length of array returned is 4, and i want 3

Comment: @EricKlaus So if I got it right you want to split by the "go" followed by a line break and an empty line?  ... I need to think bout that ...  .... ....

Comment: @Olaf, that's right, OR when there is only GO in the line. (those two are pretty much the same in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
# Sample input, defined via a verbatim here-string.
$str = @'
aago go sdf
bbbgo go sdf gojh
go

zzzz bbb
go

sdkfgo go sdfd
go
'@ 

$str -split '(?m)^go\s*$' -ne '' |  # Split as desired.
  ForEach-Object { "«$_»" }         # Visualize the results
```

For an explanation of the [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) used with the [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) operator above and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/AbXJH2/1).

Output:

```sh
«aago go sdf
bbbgo go sdf gojh
»
«
zzzz bbb
»
«
sdkfgo go sdfd
»
```